# Free Autocomplete map on Flutter

Tags: flutter, autocomplete, openstreetmap, free, fluttermap

I'm implementing a map using openstreetmap which you guys know it is 100% free. So I want the same approach talking about searching addresses with a textfield. Is it that possible? Or I really have to generate an API key for Google or other provider like Mapbox? Thanks in advance

Here is my [map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Su2Gz.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Nominatim](https://nominatim.org/). Either setup your own server (recommended), or use their public API and conform to their rules. Note that, if using their public API, autocomplete is **strictly forbidden**.